# Adding an Array within an Array

Tags: java, arrays, addition

I have a program made in which users can make a self chosen x number of computations. So far so good. After the x number of computations have been made, I want to present the user all the wrong answers during the assessment. Everytime a user answers wrongly the Class "Erroranalysis" will be called. There I want to store the number of the calculation, the components of the calculation (Eg. 12 and 13 for "12+13"), the given answer and the result of the computation. Those are 5 variables. So after the chosen number of calculations have been done I want Java to put out: (Eg.)

"calculation number 3 was wrong. 13 + 18 = 31, you had: 32"

"calculation number 7 was wrong. 21 + 16 = 37, you had: 25"
etc etc

the 'add' is with a red curly stripe underneath. So I have no clue how to add this range of variables into an Array. And also how to get them out accordingly.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Erroranalysis
{


static ArrayList<Integer> mistakes = new ArrayList<Integer>();      

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         if (Sumup.counter <= Numberofcalculations.numcalc)
            {

           int[][] incorrect = { {Sumup.counter}, {Sumup.part1}, {Sumup.part2}, {Sumup.result}, {Sumup.answer} };

           mistakes.add(incorrect);


           }        


         if (Sumup.counter > Numberofcalculations.numcalc)
           {
           for (int i : mistakes)

           System.out.println("Calculation number "+(incorrect[0]) + " was wrong: " + (incorrect[1])+ " + " +(incorrect[2]) + " = " + (incorrect[3])+", you had: "+ (incorrect[4]));


           } 


    }

}
```

Comment: Your arraylist is this **ArrayList<Integer>** and you are trying to add data of type **int[][]**. Your focus point should be this.

Please change it to `ArrayList<Integer[][]> mistakes = new ArrayList<>();` and `Integer[][] incorrect ={ {Sumup.counter}, {Sumup.part1}, {Sumup.part2}, {Sumup.result}, {Sumup.answer} };`

Comment: this is indeed what it should be. Thanks. Somehow I still don't know how to get these printouts...as mentioned in the second 'if' part....do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you declared the wrong `ArrayList` type. `ArrayList` accepts a generic parameter that determines the type of the elements in the list.

Try this:

```
private static ArrayList<int[][]> mistakes = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
```

By passing `Integer`, you told the compiler that this is a list of `Integer` objects (`Integer` is a wrapper class for the primitive type `int`). Then, inside the method, you tried to add an element of type `int[][]` to the list, so you got a compilation error.

Comment: Well that was a great help. The top 'if' section seems to be correct now. But in the second 'if',  it seems not to recognize the variable 'incorrect' anymore. Also it is still not clear to me how to arrange that output according to my above mentioned example. So can you give some more clues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `i` instead of `incorrct`. Also, you should change its type to `int[][]`